# Word "faces" on my website url is repeated

Tags: xml, jsf

i have a problem with the development of my website...
It turns out that when navigating in it, the word "faces" is repeated every time i access more options within that page...

One example:http://www.mipagina.com/faces/faces/faces/contactenos.xhtml...

Attached the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I think it starts as a result of the URL of your welcome file. Try getting rid of the */faces/* in your welcome file declaration. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434622/facesservlet-url-patterns/22441493

Comment: Good to know; I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the preceding *faces* in your welcome-file declaration. [In my experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434622/facesservlet-url-patterns/22441493), the */faces/* url mapping doesn't work correctly. My theory would be that your welcome file leads into the web application with a *faces* prepended, mojarra goes ahead and prepends even more.

What you should now have is:

```
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
```